# What is an expression that defines a complex whereby you think you are being treated unfairly, even if you are not?

Tags: phrase-requests, psychology

I am looking for an expression akin to "persecution complex" but for when someone is convinced not that they are being persecuted, but that they are constantly getting the short end of the stick, or being treated unfairly, even though evidence suggests otherwise. For example, someone may sign a contract which is objectively fair for both parties, but that person may be convinced that they are being "had".

Similarly, in the context of an inheritance, if there are several heirs, all of whom receive a fair and equal amount of money and property. But one of the heirs may be convinced that they are getting less than the others, and no amount of information convinces them otherwise. What would that person be suffering from?

Not persecution complex, because they don't think anyone's out to persecute them; but something like "being-treated-unfairly" complex.

Comment: both *frustration* and *sense/feeling of injustice/unfairness/grievance*

Answer (score 1):

What I was looking for was "Victim Mentality" which is described in [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/mental-health/what-is-a-victim-mentality):

> Someone who acts from a place of victimhood claims things that happen to them are the fault of someone or something other than themselves. It might be the fault of their partner, family, co-worker, friend, or "the way the world is." They ferquently complain about the bad things that happen in their lives. They are reluctant to take personal responsibility, asserting that the circumstances aren’t in their control.

According to [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/victim-complex-4160276) it can also be called the "victim complex".